# Making an Ubuntu installation disc UEFI bootable

Tags: 12.04, installation, uefi, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a machine with UEFI (Windows 8). Following [Rod Books](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html), I managed to get my system to boot using rEFInd. However rEFInd does not offer me any options to boot from my Ubuntu installer disc.

Another thing...after following Rod Books' instructions, my machine greeted me with something along the lines of "The bootloader is not trusted" (my usage of the term "bootloader" is possibly wrong; I'm not well-acquainted with these terms) I got to work around this by setting up some passwords in the BIOS and putting the renamed .efi of rEFInd to the trusted list. While in this screen, it showed me the drives with a possible .efi (among them, the drive S in Rod Books' guide) and one of the drives it showed was my optical drive with an Ubuntu installer. I tried browsing for an .efi in the Ubuntu installer but found none. True enough, at Windows, I searched the drive for an .efi but found none.

So how do I make my Ubuntu installer UEFI bootable?

Comment: You may need to try with **12.10**, or wait for backports for **12.04**.  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely what Ubuntu version are you trying to install? Please specify the exact filename of the .iso image that you downloaded. My first guess is that you've got a 32-bit (i386) version, which won't be bootable in EFI mode on a 64-bit computer -- at least not without additional tedious mucking about. It's also possible that you've downloaded a Mac version (amd64+mac), which likewise also lacks EFI support. Another possibility, for rEFInd at least, is that you've accidentally reconfigured the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf` to omit the `optical` option, which is required to "see" EFI-bootable optical discs. This last possibility seems rather remote, though; by default rEFInd *does* scan for EFI-bootable optical discs.

I just checked, and in VirtualBox, at least, rEFInd has no problems detecting the EFI boot mode of an AMD64 Ubuntu 12.04 system (`ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso`).

Comment: Yeah Rod, you got that. I'm trying with a 32-bit installer---I just figured last night. I just got this installer from our sysads at work. I have used it to dual boot an old 64-bit machine originally running XP. I missed the fact that it's 32-bit. Embarrassing mistake but thanks!